# Ошибка при запуске Selenium. cannot create temp dir for user data dir

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Для тестирования приложения, написанного на django 2 хочу использовать selenium. Написал такой тест для примера:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver


class FirstTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_first_selenium_test(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
        self.driver.quit()
```

Тест падает с исключением:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
>   cannot create temp dir for user data dir   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.41,platform=Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64)

Использую python 3.5 в виртуальном окружении, selenium 3.141.0, django 2.1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каталог `/tmp` был заполнен на 100%. Веб-драйверу просто не хватало места.

Comment: Подскажите, а как освобождать место в таком случае? Такая ошибка выскакивает через раз, каждый раз приходится перезапускать пк

Comment: @ChikChirik, очень рекомендую расширить объём раздела в этом случае. У меня таких проблем более не случалось. Ещё мысль - проверьте, корректно ли завершаются процессы веб-драйвера. Быть может они аварийно завершаются и оставляют кучу мусора в /tmp?

Comment: все процессы с selenium завершаются вот так `driver.close()   driver.quit()` Подскажите, а как можно расширить раздел?

Comment: Выглядит разумно. Возможно, дело вообще не в веб-драйвере.А для изменения размера раздела что-то вроде этого должно помочь. https://anikin.pw/all/izmenenie-razmera-razdela-v-linux/

Comment: Спасибо, у меня windows только, размер раздела почему-то кажется что не причем, под программу снял выделенный сервер 40 гб, больше никакие процессы не работают, может я конечно чего не понимаю)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ, мне помогло вот это:

```
 ввел echo %temp% в командной строке Windows
 вернулось C:...\TEMP\2
 у меня папка была скрытой, открыл и проблема пропала, у кого этой папки вообще нет, то 
 стоит попробовать ее создать, как пишут проблема также пропадает.
```